# Вопрос про CSS - скрыть не влезающий текст в DIV блоке

Tags: css

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется такой код:

```
<div class="below-title-meta">
        <div class="adt">
            <img src="...img/date.png" width="12" height="13" alt="Дата"> <span class="date updated">00.00.0000</span> | <span> <img src="...img/category.png" width="14" height="13" alt="Рубрика"> <a href="https://info/" rel="category tag">Название рубрики</a><span style="display:none;" class="vcard author"><span class="fn">456</span></span>  </span>
        <div class="adt-comment">
        <img class="link-comments" src="...img/comments.png" width="15" height="14" alt="Комментарии"> <a class="link-comments" href="https://">Нет комментариев</a> 
        </div></div>

        </div>

.below-title-meta{
    background: #F7F7F7;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    color:#a2a2a2; 
    line-height:1.9;
    width:106.3%;
    margin-left:-3.1%;
    }
.below-title-meta a{
    color:#666666; text-decoration:none;
    }

  .adt{float:left;padding-left:22px;}

  .adt-comment{float:right;padding-right:16px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9n4ebw74/

**Нет комментариев** в правой стороне, а название рубрики (рубрик) в левой. Дизайн сайта резиновый. Что надо прописать, чтобы при подходе названия рубрики(рубрик) к **Нет комментариев** не происходило переноса последнего на новую строку, а название самой рубрики сокращалось многоточием.

Если это изобразить на картинке, то вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первым делом, не забывайте, что любой "резиновый" дизайн все равно должен иметь минимальную ширину, после которой он либо перестает сужаться, либо меняет свой внешний вид под мобильные устройства. По сути вопроса, у вас есть два варианта, как решить задачу с обрезанием текста.

### Вариант 1: решение на стороне бекенда

Тут все достаточно просто. В зависимости от того, какой язык вы используете, вы обрезаете название рубрики таким образом, чтобы оно влезало в ваше поле. Например, код на php:

```
// обрежем текст на определённое количество
$string = substr($string, 0, 200);
// убедимся, что текст не заканчивается знаками препинания
$string = rtrim($string, "!,.-");
// находим последний пробел, устраняем его и ставим многоточие
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '));
// выводим
echo $string."… ";
```

### Вариант 2: решение на стороне фронтенда

Тут может быть несколько подвариантов.

- использовать css
- использовать jss

Первый подвариант я бы предложил сразу откинуть, так как он будет в итоге приводить в некоторых случаях к непредсказуемым последствиям. Да и вообще, оставлять текст просто невидимым - не слишком верное решение. Но в общем-то, делается это так:

```
p.clip {
    white-space: nowrap; /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
    overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем все, что не помещается в область */
    background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
    padding: 5px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Добавляем многоточие */
   }
```

Как видите, решается достаточно просто, но нет проверки на знаки препинания, не убрать последний пробел, да и вообще разные браузеры по-разному поддерживают css.

Второй подвариант более оптимален. С одной стороны, он похож на первый вариант решения, на стороне бекенда, с другой стороны, он более гибок, так как позволяет обрезать текст динамически, в зависимости от размера экрана пользователя и соответственно в зависимости от ширины блока, где должен оказаться текст.

Самый простой вариант, когда у вас не будет определения необходимой длины, это:

```
var sliced = text.slice(0,10);
if (sliced.length < text.length) {
sliced += '...';
}
```

Тут мы обрезаем текст, и если он больше заданной длинны, то добавляем многоточие. Можете дополнить его теми же обработками, что в примере про php, самостоятельно. Ну и самое сложное - это определить размер блока, под который подстраивать ваш текст, после чего вычислить необходимое количество символов. Тут уже все сильно зависит от вашего кода, могу сказать только, что вам точно помогут две функции ванильного js:

```
// возьмем элемент, ширина которого нас интересует
var test = document.getElementById("test");
// узнаем его длину
var width = (test.clientWidth) + "px";
```

Дальше, думаю, все ясно.

Comment: Спасибо за столь всеобъемлющий ответ.  Это строчка с категориями,  обозначающая в какую категорию (категории) добавлена статья. Дизайн резиновый. Потому идеальный и оптимальный способ CSS.
Проблема в том, что конструкция CSS не работает, да и ранее я её уже пробовал https://jsfiddle.net/9n4ebw74/1/ . Скорее всего это происходит «Нет комментариев». Вот это ключевая проблема и мне хотелось бы её решить.

Comment: "Скорее всего это происходит «Нет комментариев»" - поясните, не понял

Comment: Вообще же, обязательно даже у резиновых дизайнов задают минимальную ширину. Вынесу это в ответ, важный момент тоже

Comment: Есть блок, с одной стороны категории а с другой "Нет комментариев" - на живом примере это отчётливо видно. И заголовки может и стоит ограничивать, но в данном случае это кликабельные названия категорий - они выполняют навигационную функцию. Лучше их не ограничивать, но если пользователь открыл страницу, к примеру, на мобильном, то выхода особого не остаётся.

Comment: А вот макет всей страницы https://jsfiddle.net/u0t72dgh/4/ Сейчас идёт перенос.. а хотелось бы, как на приведённой картинке в первом посте - не влезающая категория (категории) оканчивалась многоточием.

Comment: Вам там чат доступен уже? Давайте в него перейдем, проще будет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53793/discussion-between--and-useruser-name).

Comment: Благодарю! Этот ответ решил мою задачу 